# Jenkins gives me "Unexpected element "{}path" {antlib:org.apache.tools.ant}path" when i try to build my project

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, github, build.xml

I need to build me project using Jenkins whenever a push is made to my GitHub repository, however, when a push is made, Jenkins gets triggered but isn't able to successfully complete the build; giving me the following:" **BUILD FAILED** C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\ShoppingCart\LibraryShoppingCart\build.xml:1: Unexpected element "{}path" {antlib:org.apache.tools.ant}path "

Here's my build.xml:

```
<path id="NecessaryLibraries">
    <pathelement location="./UsedLibraries/junit.jar"/>
    <!--matcher-->
    <pathelement location="./UsedLibraries/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v20180420-1519.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="./UsedLibraries/org.junit.jupiter.api_5.1.0.v20180327-1502.jar"/>

    <!--<pathelement location="./UsedLibraries/jacocoant.jar"/>-->
</path>


<target name="compile-testcases" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${result.testclasses.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.test.dir}"  destdir="${result.testclasses.dir}" debug="true" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath>

            <path refid="NecessaryLibraries"/>
            <pathelement location="${result.javaclasses.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
    </javac>        
</target>

<target name="test" depends="compile-testcases">
    <!--fork : each test will run in its own JVM (to seperate test cases)-->
    <junit printsummary="true" haltonfailure="true" fork="true">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="NecessaryLibraries"></path>
            <pathelement location="${result.javaclasses.dir}"/>
            <pathelement location="${result.testclasses.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
        <batchtest >
            <fileset dir="${result.testclasses.dir}" >
                 <include name="**/*Test.class"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>

    </junit>
</target>
```

All Jar files and used libraries are copied and pasted in the 'UsedLibraries' src folder.

Comment: Ant expects the top level element to be `<project>`.

Comment: @teppic it worked. Thanks! I apologize for such a stupid question.